# How to use react hook as common component with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, notistack

I have a SnackBar.ts file as below

```
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';

const SnackBar = (message:string, isError?:boolean) => {
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  return enqueueSnackbar(message, {
    anchorOrigin: {
      horizontal: 'right',
      vertical: 'top'
    },
    variant: isError ? 'error' : 'success',
    style: { whiteSpace: 'pre-line' }
  });
};

export default SnackBar;
```

So I started use that in my compoonent tsx like below

```
    import { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { SnackBar } from '../../snackbar';

    const userEditForm: FC = (props) => {
    const mySnack = SnackBar;
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('error');
        if (!loading && submitForm) {
          if (!error) {
            mySnack('user updated');
          } else {
            mySnack(error, true);
          }
        }
      }, [error, loading, submitForm]);
       
     return ( <MyComponent /> );
}
```

I'm getting this error "`Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`"

Error is coming from this line `mySnack('user updated');`

All I wanted to do is use that `enqueueSnackbar` as a shared method.
How can I do that in typescript ?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. It looks like you're calling hooks at the root of a file, which would explain the error, or it's just an incomplete example?

Answer (score -1):

The error is exactly what it says. According to the snippet, you're trying to call `useEffect()` outside of a function just below the import that is the error.

try this,

```
import { SnackBar } from '../../snackbar';


const SomeComponent = () => {

const mySnack = SnackBar;

callSnack(){
console.log('error');
    if (!loading && submitForm) {
      if (!error) {
        mySnack('user updated');
      } else {
        mySnack(error, true);
      }
    }
}


useEffect(() => {
    callSnack();
  }, [error, loading, submitForm]);

return <div> Somehting </div>;
}
```

This should solve your issue and not sure why you're reassigning to `mySnack`, you could call `SnackBar(' ')` directly.

Also, for best practices, name files that contain React components with the extension `tsx`.

Comment: He's calling `mySnack('user updated');` inside of `useEffect`, which is another situation that would throw the error he has.

Comment: But the `useEffect` is not a didComponentMount call but a dependency change call, so It should be okay?  Since it won't cause build infinite loop?

Comment: @sameerkashyap  I tried SnackBar() and tried changing ts file to tsx. still same issue

Comment: Are you using the hook inside a function? @AMendis
else, please update your question with the error line number so we can get a better picture.

Comment: @sameerkashyap updated the question. I'm calling the mySnack('user updated'); inside useEffect

Comment: Using a hook inside `useEffect`'s callback will break the predictability that hooks need to work, which will throw the _"Invalid hook call"_ error.

Comment: @AMendis What line number is the error, and which file Is it occurring in?

Comment: @sameerkashyap it still occurs when calling mySnack()

Comment: Probably SnakcBar should be used like a hook